# Problem faced while using matcap in blender 2.79b

Tags: 3d-view, shaders, matcaps

I faced some problems in Blender using Matcap.

When I select different different textures in Blender Matcap, the texture doesn't change.

[image]

Comment: That looks like a bug to me. Did you try a fresh installation of blender?

Comment: Yes I have a fresh installation of blender 2.79b.